# Why does MVVMLite return a "Type not found in cache" error?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I made a change to an interface that I use. I instantiate an object in the ViewModelLocator that's of that interface. And I have a unit test which tests that. The unit test worked perfectly before, now it doesn't. Here's the old definition of the interface:

```
public interface IViewService
{
    bool ShowMessage(string title, string message);
}
```

And here's how I've changed it:

```
public interface IViewService
{
    System.Windows.MessageBoxResult ShowMessage(string Title, string Message, DialogButtonsEnum ButtonsToShow);
}
```

(The DialogButtonsEnum is an enumeration I've created.)

Here's the line in our ViewModelLocator class where the problem occurs:

```
static public IViewService ViewService
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewService>();
    }
}
```

it baulks on the GetInstance() call, raising this error:

HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Type not found in cache: LRAT.CoreServices.IViewService.
  Source=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras

So, what have I done wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you register the implementation of you interface?

Comment: This exception is normally thrown if you try to execute `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyInterface>();` without having called `ServiceLocator.Current.Register<IMyInterface, MyInterfaceImplementation>()`. Have you forgotten to register the implementation?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your title, it currently says the opposite your question is :)